# in drupal 7, how to get node id from node title?

Tags: drupal, load

I know the node title, and I want to get node id from the node title, I tried 2 ways but not working properly

1)

```
$title = arg(2); // get node title from the url 
$node = node_load(array('title' => $title));    
$nid = $node->nid;
print $nid;
```

errors are saying that  `Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load()` , `Trying to get property of non-object`

2)

```
 $items = entity_load('node', FALSE, array(
            'type' => 'article',
            'title' => arg(2),
    ));
```

but then what I should do ?

Comment: Usually, arg(1) is the node ID (node/16/edit). Here, arg(2) is 'edit'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node nid can be only numeric and unique value. $title it is not numeric value it is string that entered by user, $title has no any relations with $node->nid. You can have 10 different nodes with the same title. Also refer please to:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/7

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_load/7